# How to create a UICollectionView Programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX2DE.png)
Hey I'm pretty new to swift and I'm trying to make multiple collection views, so far I think I've got it correct but I'm not sure what to return on these two errors, can anyone help?

I think for the top on I just need to return the number of items.

Comment: Copy/paste code, not only screenshot. Well, what happens if for some reason it's another collectionView? You need to return a value.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `return cellC` in `if` statements, you should be write `return cellC` outside of `if` statements.
So your code should be like this:

```
if collectionView == self.ActionCollectionView {
   ...
} else if ... {
   ...
} else if ... {
   ...
}
return cellC
```